# Ubuntu 13.10 NetworkManager "Dump inconsistency detected" System Freeze

Tags: 13.10, 14.04, network-manager, freeze

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 on Asus N550JV laptop. My system gets frozen pretty randomly during the day. Sometimes it's possible to switch to terminal and then back to resolve it, other times it entirely hangs and I have to go through a reboot.

Please notice the line:
`Feb  3 18:10:10 ido-N550JV NetworkManager[883]: <warn> nl_recvmsgs() error: (-33) Dump inconsistency detected, interrupted`

After which I logged out and back in by switching to terminal, and I could continue working. Afterward, it seems this message appeared again in the logs but the system did not freeze, therefore I'm not certain the few `NetworkManager` logs before that are related. `nl_recvmsgs() error: (-33) Dump inconsistency detected, interrupted` is the only suspicious `syslog` message that may be related to these hangs.

```
Feb  3 18:09:25 ido-N550JV NetworkManager[883]: <info> (wlan0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Feb  3 18:09:25 ido-N550JV NetworkManager[883]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Feb  3 18:09:25 ido-N550JV NetworkManager[883]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Feb  3 18:09:25 ido-N550JV NetworkManager[883]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Feb  3 18:10:10 ido-N550JV NetworkManager[883]: <warn> nl_recvmsgs() error: (-33) Dump inconsistency detected, interrupted
Feb  3 18:10:41 ido-N550JV whoopsie[1105]: online
Feb  3 18:11:12 ido-N550JV dbus[479]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' (using servicehelper)
Feb  3 18:11:12 ido-N550JV dbus[479]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1'
Feb  3 18:11:12 ido-N550JV acpid: client 1190[0:0] has disconnected
Feb  3 18:11:12 ido-N550JV acpid: client 1190[0:0] has disconnected
Feb  3 18:11:12 ido-N550JV acpid: client connected from 1190[0:0]
Feb  3 18:11:12 ido-N550JV acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Feb  3 18:11:12 ido-N550JV acpid: client connected from 1190[0:0]
Feb  3 18:11:12 ido-N550JV acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Feb  3 18:11:13 ido-N550JV NetworkManager[883]: <warn> nl_recvmsgs() error: (-33) Dump inconsistency detected, interrupted
```

It's worth mentioning the graphics driver seem to work good (750m with 319.32 drivers) and on the other partition I'm running Windows 8 without any trouble, I highly doubt it's a hardware issue

---

Update: I can confirm the error above has nothing to do with the system freeze. In 14.04 (nvidia 331) the error does not log but system freezes the same way, on the same hardware. The error log is clearly not what was bothering me, so this question remains open. Have tried different gpu drivers, yadah-yadah. There's a large open topic about this on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1184451
Personally, being unable to resolve this, I've since abandoned Ubuntu entirely. Sorry, good luck to you all

Comment: I've had this before - it has turned that one of network interfaces (WiFi) was getting this error for some time (days) and than has been deactivated by Kernel, causing the other interface taking over. The result was that system was still available but under different IP. PS In very similar ASUS laptop too :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see there is a UBUNTU BUG already created, replicated and triaged here

[NetworkManager[14155]:  nl_recvmsgs() error: (-33) Dump inconsistency detected, interrupted](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1118446)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the issue is harmless and has been corrected: [Git Commit Linux Kernel](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/commit/?id=e0a972461156c12ad1be40f4a4ed84705c4603aa)

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by your touchpad, disable it and use a mouse as a test.  Then you will need to blacklist the kernel mod.

PS I have the exact same laptop ;-)